# Delete ordered sequence of numbers from BST

Tags: algorithm

I had this question during an exam, and I couldn't find a quick answer.

There is an array A containing some ordered numbers A=[1,3,6,9,11] and a BST with numbers as key.
I have to provide an efficient recursive algorithm to delete the numbers in A from the BST.

The problem I have is not in deleting the nodes, but in how to use the fact that the array is ordered in deleting the nodes.

Can someone help me with some hints?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Deletion

Comment: there is O(n+k) solution for this. For non-balanced trees it is the best you can achieve because you need to read all elements in the array [O(k)] and deleting one element in a non-balanced BST is O(n) [delete the last element in a chain] are you intrested in it? or are you looking for something more optimized for balanced BST?

Comment: Thank you amit: I don't have any assumptions on the tree so I have to consider all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possible approach.

You could simultaneously traverse both the BST (using the [standard recursive algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Traversal)) and `A` (from left to right). Each of the traversals will yield elements in increasing order. You're looking for matching elements to delete them from the tree.

A naive algorithm will have `O(size(BST))` time complexity.

In some cases you can avoid looking at the left subtree completely: the value of the "current" node in the tree gives you an upper bound on the values in the left subtree, so if this is smaller than the value of the "current" element of `A`, skip the left subtree.

You can also stop the algorithm as soon as you've exhausted `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Let a BST be represented by its root node.

The function `delete-array-from-bst` with arguments `array` and `bst` is:

- if the `array` or the `bst` is empty: return
- split the array into three subarrays, the values smaller, equal, and bigger than the `bst`'s root node value
- recurse on the subarray with the smaller values with the left sub-BST, then on the subarray with the bigger values on the right sub-BST, finally delete the equal value, if applicable

Splitting the array is a binary search, so that you do not need to compare each array value with the root node.  The subarrays can share structure with the original array.  Deleting the equal value last ensures that you do not hit the worst deletion case for each value in the array.